# Delphi - libssh2.dll load issue

Tags: delphi

I'm using ssh demo client from here: https://github.com/pult/libssh2_delphi

It is working ok on every machine (Win7, Win10 32 and 64-bit), but on virtual machine I'm getting error on loading libssh2.dll library. Tried with 32 and 64 bit libraries like described in demo.

Virtual machine: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19042) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)

This is error:
[image: Loading libssh2.dll]

I'm on the begining of implementation of SSH client in Delphi, so I could not give you any other example.

Comment: Verify that libssh2.dll and all his dependencies are available in the correct path on the virtual machine. Use [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find where your application really look for the dll.

Comment: Another useful tool is [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com).

Comment: msvcr120.dll was missing

Comment: @OndrejKelle As far as I know, [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com/) doesn't work anymore with Windows 10.

Comment: @fpiette It does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that libssh2.dll and all his dependencies are available in the correct path on the virtual machine. Use [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find where your application really look for the dll.